# Do I need Liferay jackrabbit clustered configuration when using db

Tags: java, database, configuration, liferay, cluster-computing

I configured Liferay jackrabbit to use database instead of disk store.
This Liferay will be deployed in a clustered Weblogic. I was thinking if I still need to configure jackRabbit for cluster if it is using database?

I understand that cluster configuration in repository.xml is required only when data is distributed between nodes but for my case data is in central db. Am I wrong?

-e- According to Liferay Administrator's Guide, 2nd Edition page 220 it seems that cluster config is still needed

Answer (score 0):

We are running JackRabbit on single node for a cluster Liferay env, If you are heavily using document library you might need multiple nodes for it.